# Include Selenium/Firefox in Azure Function without Docker

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, debian, azure-functions

I am trying to use Azure Functions with Python with a consumption plan to scrape a web page using Selenium with Firefox.  For the way it is going to be used, it is much more practical (and cheaper) to use a consumption plan, which means I can NOT use a Docker container.

So far I have been able to successfully include and path the binary files for Firefox along with the `geckodriver` binary file.  I am getting the following error:

```
Result: Failure
Exception: WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

This works just fine when running locally on my installation of Linux Mint.  I am uploading the Linux 64 bit binaries for Firefox into the trigger directory and accessing them from there.  Azure functions uses Debian 9.  Has anyone had any success running external programs with Python without using Docker?  I have been working on this for so long...

Comment: Looks like the FireFox version doesn't match, can you provide more information?

Comment: Can you show more information about the technology you are using now? This should be a browser compatibility issue.